# latest mono on centos

Tags: .net, linux, mono, centos

How can I install the latest version of mono (maybe from trunk) on the centos (5.3+) ?

**EDIT:** Or do I have to change my server environment to Ubuntu Server or OpenSuse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my. CentOS is a bit... restrictive with updates, to say the least. Or to avoid cursing. However, downloading the [source code package](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/) for libgdiplus and Mono and running standard `./configure;make;make install` produces a working Mono environment. There are no packages provided anywhere, sadly - if you need better support, change your distribution.

Comment: There's a better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos5-5-using-yum

Comment: This URL is no longer functional.