# Install Mono on Centos 5.5 using YUM

Tags: mono, installation, centos

How do I install the [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) 2.6.7 runtime on [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 5.5 using [YUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified)?

I know how to build Mono from the source. However, according to the page *[Getting Started With Mono Tools](http://www.mono-project.com/GettingStartedWithMonoVS)* it is possible to install the binaries directly. I'd prefer to install the binaries to avoid having to install all the development pre-requisites on a server with little disk space.

Am I supposed to add a new repository description to YUM? I tried doing that, but I must have done it wrong, because "yum list mono-core" still says the old version (1.2.4-2.el5.centos).

And, why are the .rpm's called "mono-addon-" on the release server? It's a bit confusing. It sounds like the .rpm's are an add-on to Mono. I guess they mean they are an "add-on" to the server(?).

Comment: They are called add-on because they are installed to a separate prefix than the usual system packages.  This way you can install them without conflicting with your system packages.  (More of a problem for SLES, which these packages are based on.)

Comment: Ah right - is that a standard linuxy convention?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I figured it out.

#### Create a new repository configuration file

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
vi mono.repo
```

#### Add the following lines to the file

```
[Mono]
name=Mono Stack (RHEL_5)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/RHEL_5/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/RHEL_5/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

#### Update the YUM cache to be on the safe side

```
yum clean all
```

#### Install the Mono server stack

```
yum install monotools-addon-server
```

The installed binaries will end up in "/opt/novell/mono/bin".

**You should issue the following command to set up your shell environment so that it finds Mono, mcs and the other Mono tools**

```
source /opt/novell/mono/bin/mono-addon-environment.sh
```

#### Verify the version

```
mono --version

Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (tarball Mon Jul 19 18:28:58 UTC 2010)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
```

**If you want the Mono environment to be permanent you can issue the following command.**

```
cp /opt/novell/mono/bin/mono-addon-environment.sh /etc/profile.d
```

**Happy Mono'ing!!!**

Comment: If yoy get an error "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly ‘System.IdentityModel, Version=3.0.0.0 …" install WCF: yum install mono-addon-wcf

Comment: Great stuff! These steps also make it easy to install Mono on the Amazon Linux AMI on EC2, though you have to precede most commands with 'sudo'.

Comment: +1 bloody brilliant, and here was I trying to build this from src :)

Comment: @Dave Van den Eynde On Amazon Linux AMI you can type "sudo -i" to get the root shell.

Comment: Is this still accurate? I tried it again today, but I'm getting an older version from Novell.

Comment: The novell repo is turend off. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I was able to get it installed by manually installing this rpm: rpm -Uvh http://origin-download.mono-project.com/download-stable/openSUSE_11.4/i586/mono-core-2.10.6-0.xamarin.i586.rpm

Comment: This is not working any more. You can compile from sources though. Manual is available at http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Tarball . Link to tarballs is there as well.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [octonion's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos-5-5-using-yum/3510836#3510836), if, like me, you want to use Apache mod_mono, you need to ensure you install the correct version of mod_mono by running the following, and it will get the right one:

```
yum install mod_mono-addon
```

Don't just issue `yum install mod_mono`. It may install mod_mono 1.2 version from the CentOS extras repository and not what you're actually after.

As a reference, I was getting the following error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` when running the incorrect mod_mono version:

> Root directory: / 
>   mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 6
>   System.InvalidOperationException: mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 6

It is a silly, but easy mistake to make if you new to this like me.