# Mono 2.10.5 for CentOS / RHEL 5

Tags: mono, centos, centos5, rhel, rhel5

Until now I used [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos5-5-using-yum) to install/update mono on my CentOS machines, but it seems that it's not updated since 2.10.2 anymore (may because mono isn't part of novell anymore).

**So is there a new location to get newer mono *.rpm from?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had pretty good luck with the scripts Nathan Bridgewater posts on his blog.  You can get at the latest ones here: [Mono Install Scripts](https://github.com/nathanb/iws-snippets/tree/master/mono-install-scripts).  They're pretty easy to update your parallel environment settings or mono version if needed.

You can also install [from github (see section C)](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README), but will need to get XSP and what not on your own:

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git
cd mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

(select a branch/tag after cloning as needed)

Comment: The Fedora script should work for CentOS with at most minimal tweaking.  Installing from github is pretty easy too, those scipts just take care of xsp and what not too.  You pretty much need to install from source these days.

Comment: Just confirming that the install scripts mentioned work fine on redhat 5 (with EPEL rpm installed), but there is a small bug when handling tar.gz files (check their issues before installing).