# Mono error: error CS0117: `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for `ReadLines'

Tags: mono, fedora10

I followed this thread to install Mono on my Fedora box:

[Install Mono on Centos 5.5 using YUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos5-5-using-yum)

However, when I try and compile my program using:

```
 gmcs foo.cs
```

I get:

```
  foo.cs(11,44): error CS0117: `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for `ReadLines'
/opt/novell/mono/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
```

Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

The line in question is:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 foreach(int currentMax in File.ReadLines(args[0]).Select(int.Parse)) 
 {
     ...
 }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried ReadAllLines? Maybe it's defined :)

Comment: Which version of mono? If it's an older version, it may be that the feature isn't implemented yet. I would try upgrading to the latest version if possible (2.10 I believe)

Comment: I am on 2.10:# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.2 (tarball Mon Apr 18 18:57:39 UTC 2011)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  x86
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          debugger softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the problem is that you are using the `gmcs` compiler, which is designed specifically for targeting the .Net 2.0 runtime. The list of C# compilers for mono is:

- mcs  - .Net 1.1 runtime (deprecated)
- gmcs - .Net 2.0 runtime
- smcs - .Net 2.1 runtime
- dmcs - .Net 4.0 runtime

(see [here](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) for more details)

So the compiler you should be using for targeting .Net 4.0 is `dmcs`. Instead, if you actually intended to target .Net 2.0, then use the `File.ReadAllLines` method that @kil and @minitech talked about.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `string[]`. Aside from that, I think they're equivalent, but `File.ReadLines` definitely exists.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: It doesn't exist before .NET 4.0, though.