# What repo do I use to install Mono 2+ on RHEL 5.6?

Tags: mono

I am literally pulling my hair out over here. The repo listed in [Install Mono on Centos 5.5 using YUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos5-5-using-yum) no longer exists. I have tried compiling from source, but I am getting a ton of errors. I would really love to have a repo I can install mono via yum with.

What repo can I use to install Mono with? Thank you so much!

- Jeff