# Installing Mono and mod_mono on CentOS with Yum

Tags: mono, centos, yum, centos6, mod-mono

I've been trying to find a way to get Mono into Yum, There's a similar question here:

[Install Mono on Centos 5.5 using YUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510320/install-mono-on-centos5-5-using-yum)

However this is out of date - the following repositories no longer exist:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Mono/RHEL_5/

http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/RHEL_5/

Is there another repository that I can use?

Updates:

- I'd rather use CentOS 6 but can downgrade to 5 if needed
- You can run 'yum groupinstall Mono' and 'yum install mod_mono' on CentOS 5 if you have the extras repository, but not CentOS 6. Also this is a very old version of Mono (v1) (source https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=22669)
- There's a repo here I haven't tried yet but also pretty old: http://go-mono.com/monovs-download/latest/RHEL_5/

Comment: I couldn't find a repo so in the end used Nathan Bridgewater's install scripts for Mono:
https://github.com/nathanb/iws-snippets/tree/master/mono-install-scripts

Answer (score 0):

you can install mono by typing this command:

```
yum install mono
yum install xsp
yum install mod_mono
```

Comment: This must be new - what version of CentOS is needed, what version of Mono is installed and are any additional YUM repositories needed?

Comment: More, what repo is this from? The CentOS repos contain no mono.

Comment: this doesn't work anyway - not as is provided. What repo is this?

Comment: Last time I tried, the Fedora repo have mono package. CentOS doesn't have mono because they must follow RHEL 4.4 LTS and must be binary compatible with it.

Comment: CentOS 7 is needed, and the repo is https://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos7-stable.repo